# How to Get Sum of column value, after groupby another column in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas data frame, as shown below, with multiple columns and would like to get the total of column, 'Score' after grouby 'Region','Team'.

input: [input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7j5e.png)

**Code**:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv(txtfile, sep='\t')
df=df.groupby(['Region','Team']).Score.count().to_frame('New_Score').reset_index()
df.to_csv('Counts.txt',sep='\t',index=False)
```

Expected_output:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0ksq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives your expected output :

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Team','Region']).sum()
df2.rename(columns = {'Score' : 'New Score'}, inplace = True)
df2.reset_index()
```